# Set @Html.TextBoxFor to readonly. MVC, Visual Basic

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have the following line of code:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.EmployeeName, New With {.htmlAttributes = New With {.class = "form-control"})
```

I am passing the default value of this textbox through from my controller, thus I'd like to make this field visible yet read only.

I've tried using:

```
@readonly = "readonly"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

To make it read only

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.Total, new {@class ="form-control", @readonly="true"})
```

To disable

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.Total, new {@class ="form-control", @disabled="true"})
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.Total, new {@class ="form-control", @disabled="disabled"})
```